# How do I visualize algebraic products?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, motivation

I think I have no or a little problem with analyzing given algebraic products. That is, I know properties of direct, semi-direct and free products. For example, the free product $G\ast H$ is a group which contains both $G$ and $H$, and $G$ and $H$ does not affect each other in this product. And the semi-direct product $H\rtimes K$ is a group in which $H$ is normal and $K$ is a complement of $H$.

However, to be honest, I think I cannot visualize them clearly. While I have a very clear image of topological products, when it comes to algebra, I lose my intuition.

I think this is maybe because I don't know motivations of those products. (Maybe without motivations, there is a way to visualize them. If you know how, please teach me.) For example, when constructing semi-direct product, I have no idea why such specific homomorphich $\phi:K\rightarrow Aut(H)$ should be used to make an object one intends.

To sum up:

1. How do I visualize products so that I know which product should I take to construct an object I want.
2. Motivations?

Thank you in advance:)

EDIT:

For example, let $X$ be a metric space and $X^I$ be a space equipped with uniform topology. I draw this for a neighborhood of $f\in X^I$.

[image]

And for a topological open sets, I always imagine it to be an region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ without a boundary.

I want to know if there is a similar way to visualize them just like these examples

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you want here... If you think that you have a satiafactory visualization for products of topological spaces, use it for groups too. As you go along, experience and practice will slowly shape that into something more precise.

Comment: To know which proeuct you want, you have to know what properties each product has and what properties you need in each situation. That is quite independent of whatever «visualization» of products you may possibly have.

Comment: http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Category_Theory/Products_and_Coproducts

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't get how topological product and algeraic product are related.. Maybe "direct products" and few "free products" would be visualized in that way, but I don't get how in general they would.

Comment: As I said, I have absolutely no idea of what you mean by visualizing products. Since you have nos explained this, it is rather impossible for pretty much anyone to help you.

Comment: You visualize them with universal properties, unless you have something specific.

Comment: My *guess* is that you have been taught several constructions of «products» but have never really seen them used to do anything, and that you want some kind of intuition about when each is used. I can only tell you that by using them and by learning more you will learn when, each of them is called for. I suggest you keep studing group theory for some time, do a few hundred exercises and then revisit this question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Edited my post.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Okay.. I'll do as you suggest. Thank you

Comment: abstract algebra means there is nothing to visualize.